# Python 3.8: Bytes to a list of hex

Tags: python-3.x, byte

I'm currently banging by head bloody over this problem I have:

I have a method where I receive a byte input of a defined length of 8:

```
def ConvertToHexAndSend(serialnumber):
   if len(serialnumber) != 8:
      throw a good exception...
   Some good converter code here..
```

The method shall then take the serialnumber and split it into a list with the size 4.

**Example:**

```
serialnumber = b'12345678'
```

Expected output:

```
[0x12, 0x34, 0x56, 0x78]
```

What I have tried so far:

```
new_list = list(serialnumber) # Gives a list of [49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56] and then:
first byte = new_list[0] << 8 + new_list[1] # gives some riddish value
```

and

```
hex(serialnumber[0]) # Gives '0x32' string
```

and

```
first_byte = serialnumber[0] + serialnumber[1] # Gives int 99
```

But no success so far.. any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want something like:

```
result = list(bytes.fromhex(serialnumber.decode('ascii')))
```

Your `bytes` are represent a hex-string. So use the `bytes.fromhex` to read that (converting the `bytes` to `str` first), and you can use `list` to get a list of `int` objects from the new resulting `bytes` object

Comment: omg, thanks! I really don't understand how it works, but I will try to read up on these methods! But thanks again!!